# Android HLS Streaming using .m3u8 url, getting an error code -1011 and stream hangs

Tags: android, streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I just got brought onto a project that a previous employee was working on so I'm still learning his code. There has been an issue where, while streaming, the stream randomly stops.

The app I'm using is connected to a network, and on the same network there is a dongle that is connected to an Over-the-air Dish. This dish just catches local TV station's free over-the-air broadcasts and converts into HLS streaming that can be used by the Android device to stream on the native Android player.

This is what I found in the log files around the time the stream stops:

```
12-20 11:34:50.346  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154389333 us, original 155277333 us
12-20 11:34:50.346  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154410666 us, original 155298666 us
12-20 11:34:50.346  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154432000 us, original 155320000 us
12-20 11:34:50.366  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154007533 us, original 154895533 us
12-20 11:34:50.401  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154040900 us, original 154928900 us
12-20 11:34:50.411  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154453333 us, original 155341333 us
12-20 11:34:50.411  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154474666 us, original 155362666 us
12-20 11:34:50.411  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154496000 us, original 155384000 us
12-20 11:34:50.436  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154174366 us, original 155062366 us
12-20 11:34:50.471  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154107633 us, original 154995633 us
12-20 11:34:50.476  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154517333 us, original 155405333 us
12-20 11:34:50.476  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154538666 us, original 155426666 us
12-20 11:34:50.476  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.486  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.496  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.506  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154141000 us, original 155029000 us
12-20 11:34:50.511  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.521  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.531  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.536  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154274466 us, original 155162466 us
12-20 11:34:50.541  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.551  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.561  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.571  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154207733 us, original 155095733 us
12-20 11:34:50.571  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.581  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.591  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.601  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.611  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154241100 us, original 155129100 us
12-20 11:34:50.611  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.626  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.636  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.646  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154374566 us, original 155262566 us
12-20 11:34:50.646  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.656  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.666  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.676  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.676  2706 29007 V LiveSession: onPollBuffering: mSwitchInProgress 0, mReconfigurationInProgress 0, mInPreparationPhase 0, mCurBandwidthIndex 0, mStreamMask 0x3
12-20 11:34:50.676  2706 29007 V LiveSession: [audio] buffered 0 us
12-20 11:34:50.676  2706 29007 V LiveSession: [video] buffered 900900 us
12-20 11:34:50.676  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154307833 us, original 155195833 us
12-20 11:34:50.686  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.696  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.711  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.711  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154341200 us, original 155229200 us
12-20 11:34:50.721  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.726  4330  4330 D NetworkController: updateCarrierText : DR-GB02
12-20 11:34:50.731  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.741  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.741  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154474666 us, original 155362666 us
12-20 11:34:50.751  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.761  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.771  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154407933 us, original 155295933 us
12-20 11:34:50.771  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.781  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.791  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.801  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154441300 us, original 155329300 us
12-20 11:34:50.801  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.811  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.821  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.836  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.841  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154574766 us, original 155462766 us
12-20 11:34:50.846  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.856  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.866  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.876  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.876  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154508033 us, original 155396033 us
12-20 11:34:50.886  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.896  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.906  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154541400 us, original 155429400 us
12-20 11:34:50.906  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.916  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.926  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.936  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154674866 us, original 155562866 us
12-20 11:34:50.936  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.946  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.961  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.971  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.971  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154608133 us, original 155496133 us
12-20 11:34:50.981  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:50.991  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:51.001  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:51.006  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154641500 us, original 155529500 us
12-20 11:34:51.011  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:51.021  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:51.031  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:51.041  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154774966 us, original 155662966 us
12-20 11:34:51.041  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:51.041  2706 29008 V PlaylistFetcher: [fetcher-0] [audio] buffered 0
12-20 11:34:51.041  2706 29008 V PlaylistFetcher: [fetcher-0] [video] buffered 500500
12-20 11:34:51.041  2706 29008 V PlaylistFetcher: [fetcher-0] monitoring, buffered=0 < 30000000
12-20 11:34:51.046  2706 29008 I PlaylistFetcher: lastDownLoadDiff[2]
12-20 11:34:51.046  2706 29008 I PlaylistFetcher:  mNumRetries[5]
12-20 11:34:51.046 21652 21731 D MediaHTTPConnection: setReadTimeOut =  300000000ms
12-20 11:34:51.051  2706 29008 V MediaHTTP: connection established 
12-20 11:34:51.051  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:51.051 21652 21901 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: Hongbao
12-20 11:34:51.056 21652 21901 D MediaHTTPConnection: setReadTimeout with 300000000ms
12-20 11:34:51.056 21652 21901 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-20 11:34:51.056 21652 21901 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: Hongbao
12-20 11:34:51.056 21652 21901 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-20 11:34:51.061  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:51.071  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154708233 us, original 155596233 us
12-20 11:34:51.071  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=0)
12-20 11:34:51.076 21652 21901 I MediaHTTPConnection: response code = 200
12-20 11:34:51.076 21652 21901 V MediaHTTPConnection: mTotalSize is 283
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29008 V MediaHTTP: disconnect called
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29008 V MediaHTTP: disconnect called
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29008 E PlaylistFetcher: Cannot find sequence number 1146 in playlist (contains 1140 - 1145)
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29008 V PlaylistFetcher: [fetcher-0] [video] queueAccessUnit, timeUs=156130100
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29008 V PlaylistFetcher: [fetcher-0] [audio] queueAccessUnit, timeUs=155448000
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29007 E LiveSession: XXX Received error -1011 from PlaylistFetcher.
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154560000 us, original 155448000 us
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29007 V LiveSession: cancelBandwidthSwitch: mSwitchGen(0)++, orig 0, cur 0
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29007 V LiveSession: notifyBufferingUpdate: percentage=100%
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29007 V LiveSession: stopBufferingIfNecessary: mInPreparationPhase=0, mBuffering=0
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29006 V NuPlayer: kWhatSourceNotify with buffering-update for NuPlayer 100
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29006 V NuPlayer: msg : 3, ext1 : 100, ext2 : 0
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29006 D NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xa7c82640), (3, 100, 0)
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29006 V MediaPlayerService: [90] notify (0xaf25b280, 3, 100, 0)
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29045 V LiveSession: [audio] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=-1011)
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29045 I NuPlayerDecoder: End of Stream
12-20 11:34:51.086 21652 21731 V MediaPlayer: message received msg=3, ext1=100, ext2=0
12-20 11:34:51.086  2706 29045 I NuPlayerDecoder: [audio] saw output EOS
12-20 11:34:51.086  2706 29042 I NuPlayerRenderer: onQueueEOS audio finalResult : -1011
12-20 11:34:51.086  2706 29042 I NuPlayerRenderer: [audio] notifyEOS() End of Stream, delayUs : 319992
12-20 11:34:51.086  2706 29042 V AudioSink: stop
12-20 11:34:51.086 21652 21731 V MediaPlayer: buffering 100
12-20 11:34:51.086 21652 21731 V MediaPlayer: callback application
12-20 11:34:51.086 21652 21731 V MediaPlayer: back from callback
12-20 11:34:51.106  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154741600 us, original 155629600 us
12-20 11:34:51.146  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154875066 us, original 155763066 us
12-20 11:34:51.176  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154808333 us, original 155696333 us
12-20 11:34:51.211  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154841700 us, original 155729700 us
12-20 11:34:51.246  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154975166 us, original 155863166 us
12-20 11:34:51.276  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154908433 us, original 155796433 us
12-20 11:34:51.311  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 154941800 us, original 155829800 us
12-20 11:34:51.346  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 155075266 us, original 155963266 us
12-20 11:34:51.381  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 155008533 us, original 155896533 us
12-20 11:34:51.406  2706 29006 I NuPlayerRenderer: reachedAudioEOS (1)
12-20 11:34:51.406  2706 29006 V NuPlayer: reached audio EOS
12-20 11:34:51.411  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 155041900 us, original 155929900 us
12-20 11:34:51.431  2706  3488 D AudioSAEffectSec: EffectRelease pContext = 0xadf2e7c0, SessionId = 1035
12-20 11:34:51.431  2706  3488 D AudioSAEffectSec: EffectRelease : All effects are no longer instantiated
12-20 11:34:51.431  2706  3488 D AudioSAEffectSec: AudioSAEffectSec::releaseSA 
12-20 11:34:51.431  2706  3488 D AudioSASec: AudioSASec::Close 
12-20 11:34:51.431  2706  3488 D AudioSAEffectSec: AudioSAEffectSec::~AudioSAEffectSec 
12-20 11:34:51.431  2706  3488 D AudioSASec: AudioSASec::~AudioSASec() + 
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 D AudioSASec: Samsung_SoundAlive_play_Factory::Destroy(mSoundAlive)
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 D AudioSASec: AudioSASec::~AudioSASec() - 
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 W MySoundEffect: MySoundEffect_setEnabled() MySound is already disabled
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 D MySoundEffect: EffectRelease : All effects are no longer instantiated
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 D MySound : MySound::Close 
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 D MySoundEffect: MySoundEffect::~MySoundEffect 
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 W MySpaceEffect: MySpaceEffect_setEnabled() MySpace is already disabled
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 D MySpaceEffect: EffectRelease : All effects are no longer instantiated
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 D MySpace : MySpace::Close 
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 D MySpaceEffect: MySpaceEffect::~MySpaceEffect 
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 D MySpace : MySpace::~MySpace() -
12-20 11:34:51.436  2706  3488 I APM::AudioPolicyManager: stopOutput() output 2, stream 3, session 1035
12-20 11:34:51.451  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 155175366 us, original 156063366 us
12-20 11:34:51.456  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 155108633 us, original 155996633 us
12-20 11:34:51.461  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 155142000 us, original 156030000 us
12-20 11:34:51.476  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 155275466 us, original 156163466 us
12-20 11:34:51.541  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 155208733 us, original 156096733 us
12-20 11:34:51.616  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: time 155242100 us, original 156130100 us
12-20 11:34:51.646  2706 29043 V LiveSession: [video] dequeueAccessUnit: no buffer available (finalResult=-1011)
```

At 11:34:50.476, there is a point where there is no buffer available. Then at 11:34:51.081, there is a message saying that PlaylistFetcher cannot find sequence number and then a few lines later, there is the following error:

```
12-20 11:34:51.081  2706 29007 E LiveSession: XXX Received error -1011 from PlaylistFetcher.
```

What is Live Session error -1011?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Session error -1011 is `stagefright/MediaErrors.h`:

```
MEDIA_ERROR_BASE        = -1000,
...
ERROR_END_OF_STREAM     = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 11,
```

[android.googlesource.com](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h)

Looks like the source went AWOL and your input buffer underflowed.

Comment: Is it possible to listen for this error? If so, maybe I could try to initialize the stream again